# IOS/Objective-C: Hide subviews of view in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, hidden

I was of the impression that when you hide a view, you also hide all of its subviews.

In this case, I have a view within a `UITableViewCell` that I call `topView`.  Using Storyboard, I have given it an instance variable `self.topView`--dragged to the `UITableViewCell.h`. `topView` has a number of subviews created in storyboard such as `myLabel`.  In order to hide all the subviews at once, I would have thought that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of the tableview that references the cell I could just say:

```
self.topView.hidden=YES;
```

However, that is having no effect.  To hide the elements which also have ivars, I need to hide each one individually as in:

```
self.myLabel.hidden=YES;  //that works
```

Am I misinformed about subviews getting hidden when the superview is hidden.  Could it have something to do with this being in a cell?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: Screenshot of IB

[image]

Comment: what does `topView` point exactly? to the instance of table-view-cell? or the `contentView` of the instance? or that is a third thing?

Comment: Hiding a view does hide its subviews, are you sure the views are actually subviews of the view you are trying to hide ? Maybe include a screenshot of the interface builder layout

Comment: Agree with @SeanLintern88, I haven't tested this, but there's a chance subviews that aren't clipped by the hidden superview don't appear hidden.  So the other thing to note in debug / log output is whether the subview frames are contained by the topView frame.

Comment: topView points to a UIView called topView.  It is a subview of Content View which is, in turn, a subview of Cell.  topView has a bunch of subviews that I want to hide all at once.

Comment: I added the screenshot.  I'm pretty sure the subview frames--at least most of them lie inside the bounds of the topview.

Comment: You can try to hide view with tag to check what's wrong.

Comment: Wether the subviews are within bounds or not should not matter if you hide the 'Top view' the subs should hide, are you expecting some other behaviour such as cell gets smaller ?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with autolayout.  I do want the topview to disappear when empty although I can also handle this by modifying the height constraint.  It just does not make sense that the subviews are not responding to the topview being hidden.

Comment: Try to log the height of top view and the last view(in your case its lable) inside the top view. Make sure that the top view height is enough that it includes all the subviews inside.

Answer (score 0):

Using KVC:

[topView.subviews setValue:@YES forKeyPath:@"hidden"];

Comment: I tried this previously.  It works for most of the subviews but not for the buttons.  Also, if in fact all the subviews should be hidden as soon as you hide the superview, it doesn't seem like this would be necessary